# Tailwind CSS Dynamic State Updates But Not Rendered Correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

My design has 3 divs. A left panel (filters), the main content which contains a cards displayed in a grid and a right panel (info). The side panels have a button which user can open and close like a drawer. I offset the main content by using tailwinds `ml` for margin-left relative to the left panels width and similar to right.

If panel is opened, extend width and update the grid's left offset with margin left. And vice versa.

Here is my code. The right panel works fine. But the left panel is problematic. By default the left panel is open. When I click on the button to close it via the callback method with `toggleFilterVisibility` the panel closes but the grid displays with no margin (which completely covers the left panel to re-open). I inspected the component's states and they are updating with the callback as expected. I also removed the `ml-[${filterPanelWidth}px]` with the string literals `ml-[65px]` and `ml-[250px]` which are rendered correctly.

I suspect I am implementing the dynamic render with tailwind incorrect or its rendering before waiting for the state updates somehow. `console.log(filterPanelWidth)` and clicking the button shows the correct state changes for both filterPanelWidth and filterPanelVisibility.

```
<div className={`bg-gray-100 pt-14 ml-[${filterPanelWidth}px]`}>
```

```js
import FilterPanel from "../components/FilterSidePanel";
import InfoPanel from "../components/InfoSidePanel";
import CardGridPanel from "../components/CardGridPanel";

const HomeRoute: React.FC = () => {
  const [filterPanelWidth, setFilterPanelWidth] = useState(250);
  const [isFilterPanelVisible, setFilterPanelVisibility] = useState(true);
  const [infoPanelWidth, setInfoPanelWidth] = useState(45);
  const [isInfoPanelVisible, setInfoPanelVisiblity] = useState(false);

  const toggleFilterVisibility = () => {
    if (isFilterPanelVisible) {
      setFilterPanelWidth(65);
    } else {
      setFilterPanelWidth(250);
    }
    setFilterPanelVisibility(!isFilterPanelVisible);
  };

  const toggleInfoVisibility = () => {
    if (isInfoPanelVisible) {
      setInfoPanelWidth(45);
    } else {
      setInfoPanelWidth(600);
    }
    setInfoPanelVisiblity(!isInfoPanelVisible);
  };

  return (

    <>
      <div className="main-content w-full bg-gray-100">
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="left-sidepanel-content bg-white fixed h-screen">
            <FilterPanel toggleVisibility={toggleFilterVisibility} isVisible={isFilterPanelVisible}/>
          </div>
          <div className={`bg-gray-100 pt-14 ml-[${filterPanelWidth}px]`}>
            <CardGridPanel />
          </div>
          <div className={`right-sidepanel-content right-0  bg-white w-[${infoPanelWidth}px] fixed h-screen`}> 
            <InfoPanel toggleVisibility={toggleInfoVisibility} isVisible={isInfoPanelVisible}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeRoute;
```

**Update 1:** After looking at the docs I see I tried to apply the dynamic rendering for tailwind like so:

```js
          <div className="bg-gray-100 pt-14 {{ isFilterPanelVisible ? 'ml-[250px]' : 'ml-[65px]' }}">
            <CardGridPanel />
          </div>
```

but when inspecting the elements I see the following literal string. How do I resolve this? I also tried to replace the quotes with backticks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make dynamic class names like that in Tailwind. The classes must be compile-time constants. Instead of doing `ml-[${filterPanelWidth}px]` you must do something like `isFilterPanelVisible ? 'ml-[65px]' : 'ml-[250px]'`. You can read more about it in the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).

Comment: This makes sense. I tried to apply the solution as you provided but it evaluates it as a string literal. (See bottom of post for update). What am I doing wrong in my case?

Comment: You have to use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) by using backticks (\`) instead of regular quotes ("). `<div className=\`bg-gray-100 pt-14 ${ isFilterPanelVisible ? 'ml-[250px]' : 'ml-[65px]' }\`>`

Comment: I forgot to label my project is typescript. So I additionally wrapped the backticks with {} like so ```<div className={`bg-gray-100 pt-14 ${ isFilterPanelVisible ? 'ml-[250px]' : 'ml-[65px]' }`}>```. It works fine now. Thanks! Answer accepted.

Comment: Also is it just a coincidence the right panel worked? The code for each element are the same. Im surprised left filter panel was breaking while the right info didnt.

Comment: That is indeed a coincidence and only works because of hot reloading. It would not work in production, and is unstable even in development. Glad you made it work though! :)